# Thumbnail of video with FFMPEG and PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm creating thumbnail with phpcode:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

Instead of a output file I prefer to get a base64 variable.

What is the best to do that?

Example way:

1. Save file anywhere
2. Get file base64 with type, something like:

   > $content =
   >   'data:'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
3. Delete file

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'thumbnail_');
rename($temp_file, $temp_file .= '.png');
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i '.$url.' -ss 00:00:1 -vframes 1 '.$temp_file.' 2>&1';
shell_exec($cmd );
$content = 'data:'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp_file));
```